# HDD unique identifier

Tags: automounting

I would like to automount some hdd on logon, how can I check if connected HDD (via USB) is exactly that HDD which I am thinking of, and that there were no partition changes on it.

Above information I would use to identify my encrypted HDD, or maybe some other values I should use... ?

Answer (score 1):

`ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` will help you.

Comment: but this can be spoofed..